# How do you reverse engineer you phone to see how it works?

Tags: blackberry, operating-system, reverse-engineering

I am trying to find out how people are able to make their own OS for phone and I want to learn by doing to my old phone which is a blackberry curve 8530. Where will I begin?

Comment: How much computing have you studied?  I strongly suspect you have never studied Operating Systems, since if you had, I don't think you would be asking this question.  And if you haven't studied Operating Systems, then I suggest you do some classes (if not a degree), and then revisit this question.  I'm not trying to be negative, but reverse engineering an OS is not the right way to try to figure something like this out.  And especially not a BlackBerry OS - since it is not open source.

Comment: I'm currently getting my degree in CS from penn State. But the classes I'm taking right now hasn't been hands on but more discrete math and the basics to arms architecture. So I wanted to something more hands on.